# How to show the parameter in message? laravel validator

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-validation

> Note: I done searching a solution from other similar questions but none helped.

I have created a customed validator inside **AppServiceProvider.php**

```
Validator::extend('eligible_age', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
    //some statements here
});
```

The validator works perfectly like example below

`'birthdate' => 'required|eligible_age:22'`

My question is how can I show an error message **with parameter**? like example below:

`The birthdate is not eligible. (must at least 22 years old).`

Comment: You have to define error message in your lang (`validation.php`) file. See the reference: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#using-extensions

Comment: I realized that this field is not of type integer that's what I deleted my answer. Provide more description for your issue to be more clear what you asking about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use [addReplacer](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.html) to include a named parameter for example **age**. See example below.

**Solution 1**. Directly put the message inside the validator.

```
Validator::extend('eligible_age', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {

    $validator->addReplacer('eligible_age', function($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters){
        return str_replace([':age'], $parameters, 'The '. $attribute .' is not eligible. (must at least :age years old).');
    });

    //return either true or false
});
```

**Solution 2**. Just name the parameter, and set the message inside the validation.php.

```
Validator::extend('eligible_age', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {

    $validator->addReplacer('eligible_age', function($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters){
        return str_replace([':age'], $parameters, $message);
    });

    //return either true or false
});
```

And in your message in **lang\en\validation.php**, you can use age to display the parameter.

```
'eligible_age' => 'The :attribute is not eligible. (must at least :age years old).'
```